# SugarCRM rest API order by not working

Tags: php, api, rest, sugarcrm

I try to sort records returned by the `get_entry_list` rest api method, and it doesn't working.

Request JSON:

```
{
   "session":"mj95dgk1ldtd2m96u02oj0u3r2",
   "module_name":"Accounts",
   "query":"accounts.name LIKE 'Air%'",
   "order_by":"accounts.name desc",
   "offset":0,
   "select_fields":[

   ],
   "link_name_to_fields_array":"",
   "max_result":100,
   "deleted":0,
   "favorites":false
}
```

I'm using api version 4.1.

Results are not sorted even using `ASC` or `DESC` sorting method.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve the problem based on this link
https://web.sugarcrm.com/support/issues/806c9fb3-6712-abd6-3106-5287d5398699

Proposed fix:
in service/v4/SugarWebServiceUtilv4.php
Around line 89: remove or comment the following line:
$order_by=$seed->process_order_by($order_by, null);

It certainly would be better to fix that in SugarBean.php (process_order_by) where the following test was removed:
if (strchr($value,'.') === false)

Answer (score -1):

it seems like this is bug in sugar crm ( Bug :59526 ) .

[order by not working with web service](http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/need-help-how-sort-records-order_by-descending-order-84127/)

But you can also fetch the record by creating your own method for Api , i hope this helps !

Comment: about bug i am not sure , how to solve but you can create your own Api methods according to your needs !